# Sort WooCommerce products reviews by date

Tags: wordpress, date, sorting, woocommerce

One question please, how could I sort product reviews of WooCommerce by date in WP_Query? 'orderby'=> 'date' is not working. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, from the WordPress Dashboard, go to Settings, Discussion and set "Comments should be displayed with the [Older] comments at the top of each page" to "Newer"

Answer (score 0):

If there is no special condition that forces you to use WP_Query, you can use [WP_Comment_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_comment_query/__construct/) or

```
$args = array ('post_type' => 'product');
$comments = get_comments( $args );
```

these code to get product reviews. If you choose using one of those, as it states in the documentation, by default 'orderby' is set for 'comment_date_gmt'. Then all you need to set order ASC or DESC, which is by default DESC.